# Find T cyclic operator that has exactly N distinct T-invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $T$ be a cyclic operator on $R^3$, and let $N$ be the number of distinct T-invariant subspaces. Prove that either $N$ = 4 or $N$ = 6 or $N$ = 8. For each possible value of $N$, give (with proof) an example of a cyclic operator $T$ which has exactly $N$ distinct T-invariant subspaces.

Am I supposed to assume that T is a linear operator on V, after assuming that V is a finite dimensional vector space? Also, I think I'm supposed to use the dimension of subspaces, but I don't understand how it's supposed to be used.